# Local Noetherian Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

This is exercise 8.1 in Reid "Undergraduate commutative Algebra". It asks the following: say $(A,m)$ is a local Noetherian ring. Then $m$ is principal if and only if $m/m^2$ is 1-dimensional over $k=A/m$.

My problem is that I do not understand how $m/m^2$ can be different from $0$ in $k$, since elements of $m/m^2$ are still elements of $m$ (well, they're equivalence classes but still).

Can anybody help? Ps the book most likely means by principal ideal an ideal which is generated by a single non-zero elemen.

Comment: $m/m^2$ is a module, not a subring of $k$.

Comment: The claim is $m/m^2$ is $1$-dimensional as a $k$-vector space.

Comment: Do you know Nakayama's lemma?  This could be useful here

Comment: I don’t know how they define things, but it seems to me $m/m^2$ can be zero when $A$ is a field. Not that I have any doubt it works when it is a nonfield local ring.

Comment: Why do you mention dvrs in the title if you don’t mention them in the body?

Comment: I edited the question so it did not talk of DVR's in the title, though the idea from this question is clearly from there. I agree with rschwieb that $m/m^2$ is 0 if $A$ is a field, even though the book does not exclude this case explicitly. And yes I have managed to prove it, using Nakayama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always look for the simplest example. Take the $p$-adic integers $R=\Bbb Z_p$, or if you’re not familiar with them, take $R=\Bbb Z_{(p)}$, the ring of rational numbers with no $p$ in the denominator. In either case, $\mathfrak m=pR$ and $\mathfrak m^2=p^2R$. So here, an element of $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is the same as the congruence class of a number $pm\pmod{p^2}$. You rapidly see that all the numbers $0$, $p$, $2p$, up to $(p-1)p$ are mutually incongruent modulo $p^2$, and they represent all classes. Now you see that we’re talking about a one-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb F_p=\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 5):

One of the historical motivating examples of local rings comes from analysis.  Let me describe explicitly what $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ looks like for a particular local ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$.  You'll see it's not zero, and is in fact a finite dimensional vector space over $R/\mathfrak m$.

Let $\mathbb{R}[[X_1, ... , X_n]]$ be the formal power series ring over $\mathbb{R}$, and let $R$ be the subring of $\mathbb{R}[[X_1, ... , X_n]]$ whose power series is absolutely convergent in some neighborhood of $(0, ... , 0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  So you can think of $R$ as the ring of power series functions defined in some neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  In fact, $R$ is isomorphic to the direct limit of rings $\mathcal O(U)$, where $U$ runs through the open neighborhoods of the origin in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\mathcal O(U)$ is the ring of real analytic functions $U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Then $R$ is a local ring, whose unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ is generated by $X_1, ... , X_n$.  Thus $\mathfrak m$ consists of all power series with zero constant term, and we can identify $\mathbb{R}$ with $R/\mathfrak m$.

The ideal $\mathfrak m^2$ is then generated by $X_iX_j : 1 \leq i, j \leq n$.  Thus $\mathfrak m^2$ consists of all power series whose constant term and whose coefficients belonging to $X_1, ... , X_n$ are all zero.

So if you take $\mathfrak m$, and mod out by $\mathfrak m^2$, what you're doing is taking power series with zero constant term, then killing all the terms in the power series except the terms $X_1, ... , X_n$.  Both $\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak m^2$ are naturally $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces, so the quotient $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is also an $\mathbb{R}$-vector.  Every element of $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is equal to

$$c_1X_1 + \cdots + c_nX_n + \mathfrak m^2$$

for unique $c_1, ... , c_n \in \mathbb{R}$.  Thus $\mathfrak m/\mathfrak m^2$ is a finite dimensional real vector space whose basis is the image of the $X_i$ in $\mathfrak m^2$.  This is called the *cotangent space* of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at the origin.

Comment: This is beautiful